# Installation of pip on centos 7 without any internet connection

Tags: pip

My requirement is to install PIP on Centos 2.7 VM. It has python2.7 already.
This VM doesnt have any internet connection.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you try installing locally as described [in the docs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can download archive or source file and then extract it to /usr/local/ directory.